# Return reponse status from shell script curl command

Tags: curl, sh, response, httpresponse, apache-pulsar

I have a shell creates a tenant in a `pulsar cluster`. My question is less specific to that. In the below script, how do I get a response verification? I'd like to use a conditional to confirm that the `PUT` got a `200` or not.

```
### 
### Set up resources
###

CLUSTER=standalone
TENANT=sandbox

# Create tenant
curl -L -X PUT "http://localhost:$HOST_PORT/admin/v2/tenants/$TENANT" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw "{\"allowedClusters\": [\"$CLUSTER\"]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$?` contains the return code of the last command. You can check that for a non-zero value after `curl` command.

Comment: a zero being a failure?

Comment: Zero is success. Non-zero is failure. Here is a post about Linux return codes: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-get-exit-code-of-command/

Comment: Seems to "succeed" return 0 even when I have a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--fail` option of curl. With this option, if the `PUT` is not a success, then the curl command return value will be non zero.